# Using ChartJS and JSON to render charts; Appending JSON Data to javascript yields an empty object in console.log

Tags: javascript, html, json, chart.js

I have JSON data that needs to be pushed to a javascript array. I assume this is a regular list if it was Python. I can see the data being pushed in the array in console.log in this manner "[]". When I drill down this empty array, it shows the following data that I have actually pushed:

- 0:99
- 1:92
- 2:94

All this while, my length of list is zero. It isn't making sense to me at this point. Here is my code:

```
var l = [];
var m = [];
$(function() { 
    $.getJSON('anekal.json', function(data){
        $.each(data.Percentage_Completed, function(i,f){
            l.push(f);
        });
        $.each(data.Mentor_Name, function(i,f){
            m.push(f);
        });

    });
});
console.log(l);
console.log(m);
```

How can I get the list of elements pushed from json dataset to javascript array?

Appreciate your time and help. Thank you!

Comment: Try to see the whole object using your browser inspector and doing a console.log(data) right at the start of your function to see what comes from the server. We also don't know what i or f should be.

Comment: JSON data is flowing in when I did the console.log(data).

Comment: i is index, f is the actual data that I want.

Comment: $.getJSON runs asynchronous. l and m dont hold any data yet, when the logs are called. Move the logs into to inner function of $.getJSON

Comment: So, how do I make my array available outside of function?

Answer (score 0):

The `done` method of getJSON will wait until the promise is complete, then add the data to your list.

```
$(function(){ 
  var url = "anekal.json";
  $.getJSON(url).done(function(data){
        $.each(data, function(i,f){
           l.push(f.Percentage_Completed);
           m.push(f.Mentor_Name);
        })
    }); // end of getJSON
}); // end of function
```

EDIT: The problem happens because you iterate over each property of the data, not the data itself. Changing `$.each(data.Percentage_Completed, function(i,f){` to `$.each(data, function(i,f){` and then `l.push(f);` to `l.push(f.Percentage_Completed);` seems to fill up the array.

Comment: I printed the length of the list, l. It is resulting in zero length. This seemed to have no effect.

Comment: console.log(l) yields an empty [] but when I drop down the arrow, I can see my data. Even then the length of that list is zero.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: This also didn't work. I believe the problem lies in the async nature of JSON. I need to fill up the array and keep it intact outside of function. This array will be later used to make a chart out of it.